# Leer formato o estilo de celdas en Excel con Python

Tags: python, excel

como con Python se puede de detectar, validar, leer, comparar o saber el formato o estilo de una o varias celdas en Excel, para poder filtrar y/o descartar por color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe una librería que se llama [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/), puede que sea útil para lo que quieres hacer. Según la [documentación](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html), para declarar u obtener el color de una celda puede hacerse lo siguiente:

```
>>> import xlwings as xw
>>> wb = xw.Book()
>>> xw.Range('A1').color = (255,255,255)
>>> xw.Range('A2').color
(255, 255, 255)
>>> xw.Range('A2').color = None
>>> xw.Range('A2').color is None
True
```

Actualmente xlwings sólo es compatible con Windows y OSX.

Comment: Me funcionó excelente, muchas gracias por el aporte !!