# Leer el color de una celda, fila o columna en un excel con python en linux

Tags: python, excel

el titulo es bastante explicativo.
Tengo un montón de archivos excel con unos cuantos añitos donde quien los hizo y quienes siguen haciendolos colorean las celdas para presentar parte de la información, tal como elementos modificados o eliminados respecto a la versión anterior, muy bonito y visual.

¿como puedo leer el color de las celdas, lineas y columnas?
Sé que en windows y osx esta la libreria xwins pero en linux solo he encontrado Styleframe que me permite leer el color de una columna lo que es insuficiente.

Comment: ¿Has probado openpyxl?

Comment: Gracias con openpyxl he podido leer y tratar los colores y luego ya pasarlo a pandas, es un poco lioso pero funcional

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado. Considera poner una respuesta a tu propia pregunta, mostrando un ejemplo de código de cómo se hace, pues puede ser útil a quien tenga el mismo problema. Pasado un tiempo puedes incluso aceptar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo la recomendación de abulafia respondo a mi propia pregunta:

Si usas windows quizás quieras echar un vistazo a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198605/leer-formato-o-estilo-de-celdas-en-excel-con-python?rq=1) pregunta.
En mi caso uso linux y, de todos modos, huyo de herramientas que no sean multiplataforma.

Lo primero, tener en cuenta que excel guarda de diferentes formas colores por columnas, por filas y por celdas, aplicandolas en dicho orden.

El ejemplo que voy a poner sirve para localizar todas las celdas que tengan un color determinado en una columna o celda:

```
import openpyxl  # la libreria que usaremos

tabla_excel = openpyxl.load_workbook(ruta, data_only=True)


def busca_color(color, celdas):
    element = 0
    result = list()
    for celda in celdas:
        element += 1
        if celda.fill.fgcolor.rgb == color:
            result.append(element)
    return result
```

color debe ser un color en formato hexadecimal aRGB o lo que es lo mismo, con el canal alpha en primer lugar.
Ahora solo debemos pasarle una lista de celdas a la función y nos devolverá las posiciones de aquellas que tengan el color especificado:

```
lineas = busca_color('FFFF0000', tabla_excel['A'])  # buscamos en todas las celdas de la columna 'A'
print(f'Se ha encontrado el color "{color}" en las lineas {lineas}'
```

Para mas información dirigirse a la página de la [libreria openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)